# postgresql regular expression for end of string

Tags: regex, postgresql, dns

I'm trying to define a new domain for a status expressed into 1 or 2 characters. (Possible values are: {P,T,R,AR,V,AV})

I try the following:

---

```
> CREATE DOMAIN hbdt_estadosol CHAR(2) NOT NULL
>     DEFAULT 'P'
>     CHECK   ( VALUE ~ '^(P|T|R|AR|V|AV)$' );
```

---

but when I try to insert a new value into a table using 'P' as the value, postgresql returns:

```
ERROR:  value for domain hbdt_estadosol violates check constraint "hbdt_estadosol_check"
```

I got rid of the $ on '^(P|T|R|AR|V|AV)$' and the insert sentence works fine.

I try using \Z instead of $ and inset sentence sends violation again.

What is the right regular expression?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why did you remove `$`? The `'^(P|T|R|AR|V|AV)'` pattern matches these alternatives at the start of the string only. Why do you need `\Z` now, if you removed `$`? What are your requirements? What value did you insert that it did not accept, and you thought it should? Why?

Comment: The data type is declared as `char(2)` rather than `character varying(2)`, so the value represented by `VALUE` may be 'P ' instead of 'P', as you expect.  Try changing the data type to `character varying(2)`.